# What's the idiomatic way of writing a search function in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search

I have a search algorithm for my Rails app that works right now, but I really don't think this is how it should be done. Essentially, I do something of the following nature:

```
def search
    users = User.all
    //Implement search algorithm on the users array
end
```

I really feel like this shouldn't be how I should be doing it. I feel like I'm supposed to be using `SQL` or the ActiveRecord methods to get exactly the rows I need, but when the search gets pretty intensive I feel like that would be a very tough `SQL` command to write. What's the idiomatic way of writing a search algorithm for searching for specific things in the database? For example, names. What if I wanted to search for names and inputted `ire`. I'd want `Irene` to show up before `desiree`, but both have that substring. Just an example.

Answer (score 1):

I usually elastic when I need real search, like the stemming for 'Irene' you mention:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby

For smaller needs, you can use the full text search capabilities in postgres, with a gem like this one I have used:

https://github.com/textacular/textacular

Comment: Interesting. I will definitely look into them, but I'm looking more into an answer like how would elasticsearch perform its search? Will it construct an intricate SQL query, or will it, for example, gather every row into an array and then perform the search algorithm on the array?

Comment: elasticsearch is a search engine that uses lucene at its core, please look these up for the extensive details on how these work.

Comment: @David elastic search will index the content itself in a structure that is better suited to search. It will not perform SQL queries on the database.

Comment: textacular on the other hand uses postgres, and constructs sql that takes advantage of postgres full text indexing

Comment: Which is why I use postgres :) so many excellent tools at your fingertips.